# Using a "pseudonym" online and on clients?

Tags: communication, clients

If my legal name is A, but I go online as B, then when should I let my clients know that my name is not B, but A, if that's needed at all.

Do I clarify right away "hey, just letting you know that my legal name is..."; do I wait until I need to submit a W-9; some clients don't request contracts of any forms, so do I need to clarify at all?

I do have a DBA, and I'm not impersonating anyone or using anything copyrighted or trying to cause any damage, so I think the legal part is okay.

Comment: How far apart are A and B? Can the client write a check to B and have your bank cash it?

Comment: When invoicing you have to supply your true identity. I don't think it harms to reveal it on that moment. But maybe is it already obvious that your online name is a pseudo ?

Comment: @DavidR A and B are pretty far apart, and it is not obvious that the online name is pseudo. For example, my legal name is Bob, and my online name is Alice, both of which are plausible real names. For invoicing, I have a PayPal business account, so I can invoice as Alice.

Comment: The only reason your true identity would need to be supplied to a client is for tax reporting and so that your bank will cash the checks. Many clients ask for an W9 so that they can report paying you. That form asks for legal name and any business name.